# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed even the keys are identical

Tags: c#, udp, aes, padding, packet

I wish to transmit a message and a key from a client to a server. However, I don't really understand how does the UDP packets works. Also, is there any possible that I can pass more values (more than 2) through packets?

The code below can gets the correct message and key and could be able to decrypt.

```
this.dataIdentifier = (DataIdentifier)BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 0);
int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 4);
int keyLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 8);

// Read the message field
        if (msgLength > 0)
            this.message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12, msgLength);
        else
            this.message = null;

// Read the key field
        if (keyLength > 0)
            this.secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12 + msgLength, keyLength);
        else
            this.secretKey = null;
```

---

However, when I changed the value of the GetString of the keylength it will show errors.

```
this.dataIdentifier = (DataIdentifier)BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 0);
int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 4);
int keyLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 8);

// Read the message field
        if (msgLength > 0)
            this.message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12, msgLength);
        else
            this.message = null;

// Read the key field
        if (keyLength > 0)
            this.secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12, keyLength);
        else
            this.secretKey = null;
```

Client Key
[image: Key of client]

Server Key
[image: Key of server]

Error
[image: Error message]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use UDP, vs say HTTP?

Comment: Yes, is it my school work requirement (using UDP) and I am using LAN.

Comment: UDP is unreliable and is not guaranteed to keep order. So you need to implement your own application protocol to: 1. Detect and correct out-of-order packets, 2. Detect and re-request missing packets.

Comment: Is the message the same?

Comment: @user253751 yes, they are same

Comment: Does it work when you decrypt the message in the sender without UDP?

Comment: Yes, even with the UDP in the first format, it is able to decrypt the message. However, after I changed from this
  
"this.secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12 + msgLength, keyLength); "

to

"this.secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12, keyLength);"

then it shows the error